# Python Indesign script _ How to insert a picture into a page and autofit the size?

Tags: python, adobe-indesign

I need to find a way to insert pictures into an InDesign project through a python script. But the code doesn't work.

```
myPage = myDocument.Pages.Item(1)
myRectangle = myPage.Rectangles.Add()
myRectangle.GeometricBounds = [7, 1, 9, 7]
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_path = r'C:\...\In-Design Project\AA.jpg'
img = mpimg.imread(img_path)
myRectangle.Place(img) **# Error**
```

The error is :

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (35869, 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign 2020\InDesign.exe', 'Cannot create the link resource from the given URI.', None, 0, 0), None)

I found some functions that might be helpful as below but still haven't found a solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpzwY.png)

Whether the picture is inserted into an existed frame or into a new frame doesn't matter. I just really need a feasible way to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post images of code; [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60010609/edit) to include the *text* of what you've tried. This will make it easier for us to help you and more likely that you'll get an answer.

Comment: Did you confirm that that `imread` line actually loaded something?

Comment: yes. i test it by running plt.imshow(img). The picture is there. Thanks a lot for your reply. I am not sure whether the syntax itself is right here.

Comment: It is possible InDesign itself rejects that particular image; it can be quite picky at times when it comes to well-formed input file formats. Can you place that image into a document manually?

Answer (score 0):

To place an image into a frame you need to fix the last line of your code this way:

```
myRectangle.Place(img_path)
```

The `place()` method accepts a path string, not a mathplot object.

I don't know what exactly you do mean by 'autofill' since there are the several options out there: http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pe_EmptyFrameFittingOptions.html

You can add before the last line something like this:

```
myRectangle.frameFittingOptions.fittingOnEmptyFrame = 1668575078  # CONTENT_TO_FRAME
```

or

```
myRectangle.frameFittingOptions.fittingOnEmptyFrame = 1668247152  # PROPORTIONALLY
```

or

```
myRectangle.frameFittingOptions.fittingOnEmptyFrame = 1718185072  # FILL_PROPORTIONALLY
```

etc. It depends on what do you want to gain.

---

Just for educational purposes for future readers here is the full reproducible Python code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

app = Dispatch('InDesign.Application.CS6')
myDocument = app.ActiveDocument

myPage = myDocument.Pages.Item(1)
myRectangle = myPage.Rectangles.Add()
myRectangle.GeometricBounds = [7, 1, 9, 7]

# see http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pe_EmptyFrameFittingOptions.html
# myRectangle.frameFittingOptions.fittingOnEmptyFrame = 1668575078  # CONTENT_TO_FRAME
# myRectangle.frameFittingOptions.fittingOnEmptyFrame = 1718185072  # FILL_PROPORTIONALLY
myRectangle.frameFittingOptions.fittingOnEmptyFrame = 1668247152  # PROPORTIONALLY

img_path = r'C:\...\In-Design Project\AA.jpg'
myRectangle.Place(img_path)
```