# How to place a photo in a specific location in Indesign document using C#?

Tags: c#, adobe-indesign

I need to place photos on Indesign pages, few on each of 100 pgs. I use Place function and it causes to the photo to be loaded on the cursor, and then I need to click on the location I want it. But I need it to be automatic! I mean, to finish placing the photos on the page, but it waits to the user to click.

This is the code:

```
Indesign.Page pg = doc.Pages[1];
Indesign.TextFrame frm = pg.TextFrames[1];
string txt = frm.Contents;

if (txt.Contains("ploni"))
{
    app.Place("C:\\User\\Directory\\PhotoFile.png");
}
```

I have noticed that **Indesign.Page** has another parameter in its Place function that called "InsertionPoint". But I didn't understand what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about C#, but in Extendscript InDesign DOM `Page` object has `place()` method. http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Page.html And it doesn't wait any click from a user.

You can place image at top-left corner of a page this way:

`app.activeDocument.pages[0].place("c:/temp/image.jpg")`

I believe C# uses the the more or less same object model as Extendscript.

Comment: Seems C# does wait to a click from the user. In both Place() method of Indesign.Page, Indesign.Application and Indesign.Document.

Comment: Just in case. Python via win32com module doesn't want a click as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60010609/python-indesign-script-how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-page-and-autofit-the-siz/

Comment: You can try to create a frame (or rectangle) and try to place an image into it: `...rectangle.place("...")`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, finally I created a rect, then position it, and then place the image inside. Like this:

```
InDesign.Rectangle rct = pg.Rectangles.Add(doc.Layers.FirstItem(), InDesign.idLocationOptions.idUnknown, pg);
rct.GeometricBounds = new[] { yDown, xDown, yUp, xUp };
rct.Place(@"C:\User\image.png");
```